# is there a way to check if a bash script is complete or not?

Tags: bash, shell, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to implement a [REPL (read-eval-print loop)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) in bash. If such a thing already exists, please ignore the following and answer this question with a pointer to it.

Let's use this script as an example (name it `test.sh`):

```
if true
then
  echo a
else
  echo b
fi
echo c
```

What I want to do is to read this script line by line, check if what I have read so far is a complete bash expression; if it is complete, `eval` it; otherwise keep on reading the next line. The script below illustrates my idea hopefully (it does not quite work, though).

```
x=""
while read -r line
do
  x=$x$'\n'$line  # concatenate by \n
  # the line below is certainly a bad way to go
  if eval $x 2>/dev/null; then
    eval $x  # code seems to be working, so eval it
    x=""  # empty x, and start collecting code again
  else
    echo 'incomplete expression'
  fi
done < test.sh
```

### Motivation

For a bash script, I want to parse it into syntactically complete expressions, evaluate each expression, capture the output, and finally mark up the source code and output (say, using Markdown/HTML/LaTeX/...). For example, for a script

```
echo a
echo b
```

What I want to achieve is the output like this:

````
```bash
echo a
```

```
a
```

```bash
echo b
```

```
b
```
````

instead of evaluating the whole script and capture all the output:

````
```bash
echo a
echo b
```

```
a
b
```
````

Comment: You can check your script progress by running the script as follows : sh -x secondscript.sh

Comment: @crafter thanks! but it seems that will actually execute the script; what I want is to check the completeness of the code before executing it

Comment: try `sh -n secondscript.sh` . Good luck.

Comment: More accurately, try `bash -nc "$x"` and capture `stderr`; if the command succeeds, `$x` is (probably) syntactically valid. Otherwise, if `stderr` contains "syntax error: unexpected end of file" (in the English locale), then the command is probably incomplete, and you can append the next line. Other syntax errors will not go away by adding more tokens, so you should issue a syntax error (probably by reoutputing the captured `stderr`).

Comment: To add to [shellter's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) comment, try ` bash -nc 'if true ; then echo true'` as opposed to `bash -nc 'if true ; then echo true; fi'`

Comment: Three notes: I would do the first `eval` in a subshell, in case there are side-effects that would be duplicated by the second `eval`. Second, you can do the concatenation more briefly with `x+=$'\n'$line. Third, be aware that you can't evaluate a multi-line statement (such as a full `if` statement or a loop) line-by-line like this.

Comment: Using `eval` has so many corner cases, and possible failures that it makes my head spin...    The only good way to do this is to use a lexer for bash, and run the statement through that.   pygments has a lexer for bash for example, if you're not adverse to using python.

Comment: bash itself is a REPL. Which one is the final objetive ? Do something before each command, do something after each command, ...?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I want parse the script into complete expressions, evaluate each expression, obtain the output, and finally mark up the source code and output, e.g., in Markdown. I can execute the whole script and capture all the output, but that is not what i want, e.g. for two lines of source code `echo a` and `echo b`, I want `echo a` (source), `a` (output), `echo b` (source), `b` (output), instead of `echo a \n echo b` (full source), then `a \n b` (complete output).

Comment: ...so this is "complete", meaning "syntactically complete"? That's an easier problem.

Comment: And pray to God what you `eval` isn't an expression of `sudo rm -r /`

Comment: I posted an answer about how this is basically analogous to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) but I have a hard time coming up with an example which would convincingly demonstrate this, so I deleted it.  Is my thinking incorrect?

Answer (score 6):

```
bash -n -c "$command_text"
```

...will determine whether your `$command_text` is a syntactically valid script without actually executing it.

---

Note that there's a huge breadth of space between "syntactically valid" and "correct". Consider adopting something like http://shellcheck.net/ if you want to properly parse the language.

Answer (score 4):

The following scripts should generate the Markdown output you expect.

`eval "set -n; $x"` is used to verify if the command is complete, by checking for syntax errors in the command. Only a command that has no syntax errors will be considered complete, executed, and shown in the output Markdown.

Please note that the input script that is to be processed is executed in a sub-shell and therefore will not interfere with the processing script itself (i.e. the input script can use the same variable names as the processing script and cannot change the values of variables in the processing script). The only exception are the special variables called `___internal__variable___`.

There are **two approaches** to how to achieve that, which I present below. In **Version 1**, whenever a new complete command is processed, all the statements before it are executed to create a "context" for the command. This effectively runs the input script multiple times.

In **Version 2**, the environment of the sub-shell is stored in a variable after each complete command is executed. Then, before the next command is executed, the previous environment is restored in the sub-shell.

#### Version 1

```
#!/bin/bash

x=""  # Current
y=""  # Context
while IFS= read -r line  # Keep indentation
do
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue  # Skip empty lines

    x=$x$'\n'$line  # Build a complete command
    # Check current command for syntax errors
    if (eval "set -n; $x" 2> /dev/null)
    then
        # Run the input script up to the current command
        # Run context first and ignore the output
        ___internal_variable___="$x"
        out=$(eval "$y" &>/dev/null; eval "$___internal_variable___")
        # Generate command markdown
        echo "=================="
        echo
        echo "\`\`\`bash$x"
        echo "\`\`\`"
        echo
        # Generate output markdown
        if [ -n "$out" ]
        then
            echo "Output:"
            echo
            echo "\`\`\`"
            echo "$out"
            echo "\`\`\`"
            echo
        fi
        y=$y$'\n'$line  # Build context
        x=""  # Clear command
    fi
done < input.sh
```

#### Version 2

```
#!/bin/bash

x=""  # Current command
y="true"  # Saved environment
while IFS= read -r line  # Keep indentation
do
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue  # Skip empty lines

    x=$x$'\n'$line  # Build a complete command
    # Check current command for syntax errors
    if (eval "set -n; $x" 2> /dev/null)
    then
        # Run the current command in the previously saved environment
        # Then store the output of the command as well as the new environment
        ___internal_variable_1___="$x"  # The current command
        ___internal_variable_2___="$y"  # Previously saved environment
        out=$(bash -c "${___internal_variable_2___}; printf '<<<BEGIN>>>'; ${___internal_variable_1___}; printf '<<<END>>>'; declare -p" 2>&1)
        # Separate the environment description from the command output
        y="${out#*<<<END>>>}"
        out="${out%%<<<END>>>*}"
        out="${out#*<<<BEGIN>>>}"

        # Generate command markdown
        echo "=================="
        echo
        echo "\`\`\`bash$x"
        echo "\`\`\`"
        echo
        # Generate output markdown
        if [ -n "$out" ]
        then
            echo "Output:"
            echo
            echo "\`\`\`"
            echo "$out"
            echo "\`\`\`"
            echo
        fi
        x=""  # Clear command
    fi
done < input.sh
```

#### Example

For input script `input.sh`:

```
x=10
echo "$x"
y=$(($x+1))
echo "$y"


while [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
do
    echo $y
    y=$(($y-1))
done
```

The output will be:

````
==================

```bash
x=10
```

==================

```bash
echo "$x"
```

Output:

```
10
```

==================

```bash
y=$(($x+1))
```

==================

```bash
echo "$y"
```

Output:

```
11
```

==================

```bash
while [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
do
    echo $y
    y=$(($y-1))
done
```

Output:

```
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```
````

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, the `set -n` practice I suggested in my answer turns out not to be workable for the purpose -- one needs the more expensive `bash -n -c "$x"` to ensure that an evaluation attempt is side-effect-free.

Comment: BTW, I suspect you could work something out that would maintain a single execution subshell, to avoid needing to re-execute commands (which wouldn't work so well if commands being run mutated on-disk content, for instance). If we assumed bash 4.x, for instance, you could have a shell invoked as a coprocess, and modify its output sink between commands (as by feeding an `exec >out.$((++i)) 2>&1` between inputs).

Comment: `eval "set -n; ... "` seems to work well, but that runs in a subshell in my code anyways. Regarding your second comment, yes, that should be possible, we could save the state of what `set` returns instead of re-running the code.

Comment: Yes, it's in a subshell so we don't need to worry about side effects on variables, but side effects on disk, running processes, &c. are an issue.

Comment: Created another version implementing the idea. It required being a bit creative about how to retrieve the environment state from the subshell and then restore it, but it works.

Comment: Where's the creativity needed? Serializing shell state in an `eval`able form is *exactly* what `declare -p` is for -- and doing it that way keeps all your flags (whether a variable is exported to the environment, whether it's an integer, an array, an associative array...).

Comment: (...and I still stand by my coprocess suggestion as an approach that would allow significantly better performance without needing to serialize and reload state).

Comment: (To be clear, I'm not adding an answer myself because I don't want to be responsible for making it secure against code that emits output intentionally escaping the markdown backticks and injecting HTML, or otherwise engaging in malicious behavior; if I can't make it robust, I'd rather not build a thing at all).

Comment: `declare` is indeed a better option, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Assume your test commands are stored in a file called "example". That is, using same commands than in previous answer:

```
$ cat example
x=3
echo "$x"
y=$(($x+1))
echo "$y"


while [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
do
    echo $y
    y=$(($y-1))
done
```

the command:

```
$ (echo 'PS1=; PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n =====; echo"'; cat example2 ) | bash -i
```

produces:

```
=====
x=3
=====
echo "$x"
3
=====
y=$(($x+1))
=====
echo "$y"
4
=====

=====

=====
while [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
> do
>     echo $y
>     y=$(($y-1))
> done
4
3
2
1
=====
exit
```

if you are interested also in the intermediate results of a loop, the command:

```
$ ( echo 'trap '"'"'echo; echo command: $BASH_COMMAND; echo answer:'"'"' DEBUG'; cat example ) | bash
```

results in:

```
command: x=3
answer:

command: echo "$x"
answer:
3

command: y=$(($x+1))
answer:

command: echo "$y"
answer:
4

command: [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
answer:

command: echo $y
answer:
4

command: y=$(($y-1))
answer:

command: [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
answer:

command: echo $y
answer:
3

command: y=$(($y-1))
answer:

command: [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
answer:

command: echo $y
answer:
2

command: y=$(($y-1))
answer:

command: [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
answer:

command: echo $y
answer:
1

command: y=$(($y-1))
answer:

command: [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
answer:
```

**Addendum 1**

It is not difficult to change the previous results to some other format. By example, this small perl script:

```
$ cat formatter.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

$state=4; # 0: answer, 1: first line command, 2: more command, 4: unknown

while(<>) {
#  print $state;

  if( /^===COMMAND===/ ) {
    print "===\n";
    $state=1;
    next;
  }

  if( $state == 1 ) {
    print;
    $state=2;
    next;
  }

  if( $state == 2 && /^>+ (.*)/ ) {
    print "$1\n";
    next;
  }

  if( $state == 2 ) {
    print "---\n";
    $state=0;
    redo;
  }

  if( $state == 0 ) {
    print;
    next;
  }
}
```

when used in command:

`( echo 'PS1="===COMMAND===\n"'; cat example ) | bash -i 2>&1 | ./formatter.pl`

gives this result:

```
===
x=3
===
echo "$x"
---
3
===
y=$(($x+1))
===
echo "$y"
---
4
===

===

===
while [ "$y" -gt "0" ]
do
    echo $y
    y=$(($y-1))
done
---
4
3
2
1
===
exit
```

Comment: Using `PROMPT_COMMAND ` is a very interesting idea. Is there a way to append a string after each complete command? I want something like `=== x=3 === echo "$x" --- 3 === ...`, i.e. separators between the command and its output.

Comment: @Yihui: addendum written

Comment: That is very nice. I can imagine an edge case, though. For example, `cat foo.txt` and `foo.txt` happens to contain lines that start with `>`. I think these lines will be treated as continuation of the `cat` command. I was wondering if there is a similar environment variable like `PROMPT_COMMAND` (`CONTINUE_COMMAND`?). We want this character/string to be unique enough.

Comment: @Yihui: yes, there are, it is called "PS2". By default, its value is  ">", but you can use any one more complex and improbable.

Answer (score -1):

In lieu of pidfiles, as long as your script has a uniquely identifiable name you can do something like this:

```
  #!/bin/bash
COMMAND=$0
# exit if I am already running
RUNNING=`ps --no-headers -C${COMMAND} | wc -l`
if [ ${RUNNING} -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "Previous ${COMMAND} is still running."
  exit 1
fi
... rest of script ...
```

Comment: Is this an answer for another question?

Comment: I'm guessing they looked only at the title and read "complete" to mean "finished running", even though that's not what this question is about.

Comment: ...moreover -- please don't encourage grepping `ps`. The best practice is to use a proper lockfile with `flock()` or `fcntl(LOCK_EX)`-style locking -- that way you have something automatically unlocked on reboot or SIGKILL without worrying about either PID or name collisions.