# How to change the output of a knitr chunk with bash engine

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

When running `knitr::knit()` in a `Rmd` file with this:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE)
```

```{bash}
which R
which bash
```
````

The output (a `md` file) is

````
```bash
which R
which bash
## /usr/local/bin/R
## /usr/bin/bash
```
````

Is there a way to make the output look like this:

````
```bash
which R
## /usr/local/bin/R
which bash
## /usr/bin/bash
```
````

i.e., each output below each command (like a normal `r` chunk would do with R commands)?

Comment: I thought of the same thing seven years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17820740/559676 but I don't remember now why I didn't improve the `bash` engine in **knitr**. If anyone can figure out how to do it, I'd appreciate a pull request on Github: https://github.com/yihui/knitr